# Woocommerce - update cart button, custom function

Tags: woocommerce, cart

Im in need to create custom update button function in the cart.
Basically I need to add additional input (next to quantity) in the cart and depending on the input value i need to change price of the product in the cart.
Where can I modify function which runs after I hit the update cart button? PHP function together with JS function? Any idea where are those files located and what are function names? 
Thanks in adance

Comment: first yes it's required PHP and JS and  the name of the responsible class is class `WC_Form_Handler`  and function name `update_cart_action()`

Comment: I mean the name of the hook after I hit update cart/change quantity in the cart...